# Reprojecting list of raster stacks

Tags: r, raster

I have a big list of raster stacks and I want to reproject and then clip them in R. I have done the same procedure in `ArcGIS` using `batch processing` which was significantly faster. 
It is not going well in R. Any suggestion to improve the process?

my `rstack.lst` consist of 19 raster stacks like this:

```
class       : RasterStack 
dimensions  : 4800, 7200, 34560000, 46  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution  : 463.3127, 463.3127  (x, y)
extent      : 11119505, 14455357, -5559753, -3335852  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=sinu +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6371007.181 +b=6371007.181 +units=m +no_defs 
names       : ...
```

I am using this code:

```
for (i in 1:length(rstack.lst)){
  rstack.lst[[i]] <- projectRaster(rstack.lst[[i]], crs = m.crs) # reproject
  rstack.lst[[i]] <- crop(rstack.lst[[i]], brdshp) # crop
  rstack.lst[[i]] <- mask(rstack.lst[[i]], brdshp) # mask
  print (i)
}
```

not even one I is printed after two hours!

Comment: Take a look at `gdalUtils::gdalwarp` - much faster.

Comment: What’s `m.crs`? I assume units are also in metres?

Comment: @jbaumsYES! meters. m.crs="+proj=aea +lat_1=-18 +lat_2=-36 +lat_0=0 +lon_0=132 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs"